# Download AJAX generated content using java

Tags: java, html, ajax, web

I have [a webpage](http://www.cineradoplex.de/programm/spielplan/) on which a list of movies is being displayed. The content is created using AJAX (as far as my limited knowledge would suggest...).

I want to download the content, in this case the movie playing times, using Java. I know how to download a simple website, but here my solution only gives me the following as an result instead of the playing times:

> ajaxpage('http://data.cineradoplex.de/mod/AndyCineradoProg/extern',
>   "kinoprogramm");

**How do I make my program download the results this AJAX function gives?**

Here is the code I use:

```
        String line = "";
        URL myUrl = http://www.cineradoplex.de/programm/spielplan/;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            myUrl = new URL(URL);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream()));

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response you can see the address from which actual data is retrieved

```
http://data.cineradoplex.de/mod/AndyCineradoProg/extern
```

You can request its contents and parse it.

Comment: Could you briefly explain why this works? Is this just a list and the ajax function does the layout? I was thinking more about a database from which it would extract the data...

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this web page is rendered but the idea is that in your first solution you received just the sources of the web page. It does not always contain all the data you see in your browser. When your page is loaded the browser may do some other work to render the complete page, for example - retrieve some data using ajax.